# What is the moment matrix in converting polynomial optimization problem to a quadratic optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Happy new year,
I have a function of the form below
\begin{align}
f(x,y,z)=\sum_i x_i y_i z_i + g(x)+h(z)\cr
x,y,z \in R^n
\end{align}
where $h,g$ are quadratic functions. My difficulty lies in the first term which makes it non-convex.

I read this method of converting a polynomial of any degree to a quadratic function [SDP Relaxations for Quadratic Optimization Problems Derived from Polynomial Optimization Problems](http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/ie-MARTMEVI/MKqop.pdf). But I don't understand what is the moment matrix? and what's the need for it. Because it makes the problem huge and impractical.

Question: How to convert this problem to a quadratic optimization problem with small additional variables and constraints? what is your suggestion to solve such a problem?

Any Hint or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Well, what makes the problem impractical is its non-convexity. Don't blame the moment matrix (whatever it is) :-)

Comment: :). Yes. you are correct, Michael. I mean we can't use this method for an approximation of the original problem.